# NodeJS + WS not working

Tags: node.js, websocket

I`m using this node base:
https://github.com/jessereitsma/node-base

and I`m using websockets:
https://github.com/einaros/ws

This is my code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , app = express()
  , fs = require('fs')
  , engine = require('ejs-locals')
  , webSocket = require('ws').Server;

app.set('port', 80);
app.set('wsPort', 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('[secret]'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function (controller) {
  if(controller.substr(-3) == '.js') {
    route = require('./controllers/' + controller);
    route.controller(app);
  }
});

var wss = new webSocket({port:app.get('wsPort')});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log('NEW CONNECTION');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server runs at port: ' + app.get('port'));
  console.log('Websocket server runs at port ' + app.get('wsPort'));
});
```

And when I want to connect I open the console log and type this:

new WebSocket('ws://dylan.jrnode.eu:8080');

output:

> WebSocket {binaryType: "blob", extensions: "", protocol: "", onclose:
>   null, onerror: null…}

But the Server Console don`t says 'NEW CONNECTION' why not? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it was a server problem,I could not access port 8080. Its fixed now.